# Is there a simple way to delete MRS partition in new external drive?

Tags: filesystems, storage

I just bought a 5TB external USB drive.

This is what `lsblk` shows for it:

```
% lsblk --output=NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE /dev/sdd
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL                   SIZE
sdd                                   4.6T
├─sdd1                                128M
└─sdd2 ntfs   Seagate Portable Drive  4.6T
```

I understand that the little 128M partition under `/dev/sdd1` is a "Microsoft Reserved" (MSR) partition, and that it is not needed for a Linux system like mine.

I would like to have all of the disk's available space in a single partition.

Is there a simple way, from the Unix command line, to consolidate both partitions into a single one?

(If this doing this requires reformatting, then I can add that I don't care for ntfs; ext4 would be my preference.)

Comment: If originally planning to use only with LInux better to have used gparted or gdisk to partition drive. Windows always adds the Microsoft reserved partiiton as that is required before the first NTFS partition with Windows installs. But also since external, you cannot install Windows anyway. Delete partitions, make sure drive is gpt partitioned & create new ext4 partition. Since one large partition, you do have good backups planned for data on drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify the partition by running `sudo fdisk /dev/sdd` to open the partitioning utility.

You can then create a new GPT partition table by doing `g` which will create this.

Now you can create your partition or partitions if you choose to have different sizes with the following sequence.
(ENTER means press the enter key)

```
n
ENTER (Should usually be in sequence)
ENTER (Just using the first available sector)
ENTER (Or if you want specific space do +1T for 1 TB or +512G for 512 GB)
```

This will create a partition with a number of 1, first sector will be at the start of the driver that it can use, and it will use all the drive for the partition.

You can now type `p` to list the partition table and when you are happy with your partitions you can type `w` to write to disk and exit. If you are not happy you can always type `q` to exit without saving.

Now to make the partitions ext4 you can do (for example)

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd1
```